# ccnet exec block return value?

Tags: exec, cruisecontrol.net, conditional-statements

I am working with ccnet 1.6 and am having trouble with some of the concepts.  I build my .NET solution with a batch file that returns success or failure.  Following that there are also steps to build a solution for unit tests and steps to run a batch to execute the unit tests themselves.  I was wondering is there is a way that I can access the return value ccnet gets back from the first build so that I can conditionally run the steps to build the unite tests and to run them.  I have looked, and I have found a wealth of information about ccnet, but I haven't seen how to get this return value from ccnet and I am sure it's a simple thing that I have missed.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. You could use a [Conditional Task](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Conditional_Task). However my approach would be to setup the unit tests in a separate CC.net project and use a [project trigger](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Project_Trigger) to start when the build was successful.N

Maybe you want to look into `NAnt`, `Python` or another scripting language -- my experience with batch-file have been poor.